Why is my game's lag get more worse when I play it further?
This is a prototype game about a goose who has to keep the temperature right or else the world ends. I'm trying to add in more mechanics in but I really can't move on because the lag gets worse the more you play. Is there anything I can reduce or simplify?
let gabHeatColor = 0;
let gabThermoStat = 30;

var gooseHonk;
let laserHue = 0;

//denaplesk2 game timer
let timerValue = 30;
let startButton;

let timerBar = 0; //will appear @ top screen

function preload() {
  soundFormats('wav');
  gooseHonk = loadSound('spacejoe_bird-honk-2.wav');
}

function mousePressed() { //plays goose honk
  gooseHonk.play();
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  // textAlign(CENTER);
  setInterval(timeIt, 1000);
}

function timeIt() {
  if (timerValue > 0) {
    timerValue--;
  }
}

function draw() {
  // frameRate(20);
  background(140, 140, 72);
  strokeWeight(0);
  
  fill(107, 94, 43); //floor background
  rect(0, windowHeight/1.3, windowWidth, windowHeight);
  
  fill(140, 213, 237); //window
  rect(windowWidth/3, windowHeight/7, 200, 450);
  
  //timer > winstate or gameover
  fill(0);
  if (timerValue <= 60) {
    text(timerValue + " SECONDS", width / 3, height / 10);
  } else {
    text(timerValue + " SECONDS, You WIN!", width / 3, height / 10);
    frameRate(0);
  } 
  
  if (gabThermoStat > 100) {
    gabThermoStat = 999;
    text("oops world heated", 50, 50);
    text("Oh no SECONDS, You LOSE!", width / 3, height / 10);
  } if (gabThermoStat <= 0) {
    gabThermoStat = -99;
    textSize(windowWidth/20);
    text("oops world frozen", 50, 50);
    text("NO SECONDS, You LOSE!", width / 3, height / 10);
    frameRate(2);
  }
  
  gabFan();
  gabGooseBod();
}

function gabGooseBod() {
  push(); //goose neck
  stroke(240);
  strokeWeight(30);
  line(0, windowHeight, mouseX-(mouseX/2), mouseY-25);
  pop();
  
  fill(240); //goose torso
  circle(0, windowHeight, 300);
  fill(300); //gooseHead
  rect(mouseX-(mouseX/2), mouseY-25, 50, 50); 
  circle(mouseX-(mouseX/2), mouseY-25, 100);
  fill(0);
  circle(mouseX-(mouseX/2), mouseY-25, 40); //eye
  fill(255,166,0);
  circle(mouseX-(mouseX/2)+50, mouseY, 50); //goose bill & mouth
  
  fill(300,0,0,laserHue);
  rect(mouseX-(mouseX/2), mouseY-40, mouseX-(mouseX/2), 30);
  if (mouseIsPressed === true) {
    laserHue = laserHue + 40;
  } else {
    laserHue = 0;
  }
}

function gabFan() {
  fill(220);
  rect(windowWidth/2,windowWidth/2,windowWidth/2,windowHeight/2);
  
  fill(0);
  textSize(windowWidth/20);
  text("Thermostat: " + gabThermoStat + "/100", windowWidth/2+25, windowHeight/2)
  gabThermoStat = gabThermoStat + 1;
  
  let button0 = createButton("-1"); //heats up
  // button.mouseClicked(fanButton[0]);
  button0.size(90, 70);
  button0.position(windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2);
  button0.style("font-size", "48px");
  
  let button3 = createButton("3"); //3 button
  button3.mousePressed(fanButton);
  print(button3.mousePressed(fanButton));
  button3.size(90, 70);
  button3.position(windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2 + 70);
  button3.style("font-size", "48px");
  
  let button2 = createButton("2"); //2 button
  // button.mouseClicked(fanButton[1]);
  button2.size(90, 70);
  button2.position(windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2 + 140);
  button2.style("font-size", "48px");
  
  let button1 = createButton("1"); //1 button
  // button.mouseClicked(fanButton[2]);
  button1.size(90, 70);
  button1.position(windowWidth/2, windowHeight/2 + 210);
  button1.style("font-size", "48px");
}

function fanButton() {
  gabThermoStat = gabThermoStat - 20;
  print("-20, temp lowered");
}

I was thinking it was the timer slowing things down but the lag still happened. Then maybe it could be the goose's neck? Nope not that.

I've never used P5 before, but does it auto-deregister event handlers between ticks? If not, every time draw is called, you're adding another fanButton event handler every time you do button3.mousePressed(fanButton);. If all previous handlers stay registered, fanButton will get called one extra time per click every time draw runs. You can put a print call in fanButton and see if it begins printing a million times every click to confirm that.

On every draw, you're making new buttons. You probably want to have the button variables be global, and only call createButton() inside of setup()

Thanks @Samathingamajig that fixed the lag. This will give more opportunities add more mechanics in.
